# Does there exist integer $k$, such that $x+yr=r^k$?

Tags: number-theory

Let $r=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$. If $x,y,z,w$ are integers and satisfy
$$(x+yr)(z+wr)=1,~~~ x+yr>0,$$
show  that there exists integer $k$, such that
$$x+yr=r^k$$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the ring of algebraic integers of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{5})$, which is $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$. Since $r=\dfrac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ has norm -1 in the ring, then $r$ is a unit in the ring. In fact, it is the fundamental unit of that ring. By Dirichlet's Unit Theorem, the units in this ring are of the form $\pm r^k$, where $k$ is some integer. Since by assumption that $(x+yr)(z+wr)=1,$ where $x,y$ are positive integers, then $x+yr$ is a unit in the ring $\mathbb{Z}\left[\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right]$. Since $x+yr>0$, then there exists an integer $k$ such that $x+yr=r^k.$ That proves it.

Comment: Dear Habagat, I believe the OP is looking for a proof that $r$ is the fundamental unit of $\mathbb Z[r]$.

Comment: Have you simple methods to solve it? Because this is middle school exam problem